# Node.js server giving 404 (Not Found) error

Tags: node.js

My code is

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('server.cert')
};

let requestCount = 0;

const server = https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
  requestCount++;

  // Process the request here...
  console.log("req.url:",req.url);
  if (req.url === '/') {
    res.end('Hello, world!');
  } else {
    res.statusCode = 404;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.end('Custom 404: The requested resource was not found.');
  }
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
});

server.on('request', (req, res) => {
  console.error('request:', req);
});



server.on('clientError', (error, socket) => {
  console.error('Client error:', error);
  socket.end('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n\r\n');
});


server.on('error', (error) => {
  console.error('Server error:', error);
});

process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  console.log('Received SIGINT. Shutting down...');
  server.close(() => {
    console.log('Server has stopped');
    process.exit(0);
  });
});

setInterval(() => {
  console.log(`Total requests: ${requestCount}`);
}, 5000);`
```

When I start this server I get message
Server is running on port 3000
Total requests: 0

But when I browse to https://thebomberman.net/game:3000,

I see this text,

The page can’t be found.
It looks like nothing was found at this location.

Total request remains 0.  Port 3000 is open and when I run netstat -tulnp,

I see
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      11704/node

Please advise what can be done to fix the 404 error.

I tried catching error logs and used netstat -tulnp to view port 3000 is listening.

Comment: What brings you to the idea, that (a) `/game` is part of the URL and that (b) it comes between domain and port?

Comment: You test `if (req.url === '/') {` and if it doesn't pass, send a 404. `/` !== `/game`. ‍♂️.

Comment: Removed /game and it worked. Thanks brother

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL you are using, `https://thebomberman.net/game:3000`, is wrong.

The port should follow the hostname. Try with `https://thebomberman.net:3000/game`.

You will receive a 404 anyway. You code is repliyng with 200 (Hello world) if the request path is `/` and 404 for all other paths (like `/game`).

Moreover, I don't know if you are using a reverse proxy in front of your node http process. This would change things and I would need to know how the reverse proxy is configured.

Comment: https://thebomberman.net:3000/  worked. Thanks